# Кнопка Еще в ChipGroup

Tags: android

Необходимо сделать "облако тегов", думаю делать через ChipGroup. Еще нужно чтобы можно было сворачивать ChipGroup до двух строк.

Например, если в ChipGroup очень много Chip элементов то нужно сделать так чтобы можно было свернуть до двух рядов и последний chip назвать "Еще" при нажатии все Chip`ы отображаются..

Как это можно сделать?

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <!-- Chips can be declared here, or added dynamically. -->

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

p.s. Если я правильно понял, кто-то уже внес pull request с такой фичей в [репозиторий](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/1071). Разбираюсь, но не совсем то что нужно..

Должно получится так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего нужно делать кастомный ChipGroup и там уже высчитывать его максимальную высоту и если высота превышает максимальную то скрывать нужное кол-во элементов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделал как и описывал ранее - отталкивался от готового ChipGroup. Единственный минус это отсутствие анимации какой либо. Я уже сильно привык DiffCallback. **Результат выложил на [Гит](https://github.com/Tiarait/ExtendedChipGroup).** Возможно кто сможет подружить FlowLayout и некое подобие DiffCallback'а тогда это будет идеально решение. (Или напишет свою оболочку)

---

Добавляем библиотеку

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

Ваша тема должна наследоваться от **Theme.MaterialComponents**

Задекларируем стиль с новыми переменными

```
<declare-styleable name="ChipGroup">
        <attr name="maxRow" format="reference|integer"/>
        <attr name="additionalChipMore" format="reference|string"/>
        <attr name="additionalChipHide" format="reference|string"/>
        <attr name="additionalChipColor" format="reference|color"/>
        <attr name="additionalChipColorPressed" format="reference|color"/>
        <attr name="additionalTextColor" format="reference|color"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="lineSpacing"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="itemSpacing"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

Дальше отдельно выложил файл на гите [ExtendedChipGroup.kt](https://github.com/Tiarait/ExtendedChipGroup/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/tiarait/extendedchipgroup/ExtendedChipGroup.kt), тут попытаюсь объяснить вкратце. Для начала в конструкторе достаем все переменные из стилей, по сколько некоторые переменные нам нельзя вытянуть, хотя мы и наследуемся от ChipGroup, то придется местами продублировать код. Или же добавить в билд

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'RestrictedApi'
}
```

Я пошел по первому пути. Далее переписываем функцию **onLayout** и там где идет подсчет строк, а именно в цикле где **rowCount++** добавляется кусок кода

```
//если строк больше чем maxRow - заменяем последний элемент пред строки на
//"chipMoreTitle/ЕЩЕ (колво оставшихся)"
if (row > maxRow && (i - 1) > 0  && chipMoreTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                getChildAt(i).visibility = View.GONE
                val showChip = (getChildAt(i - 1) as Chip)
                showChip.chipBackgroundColor = colorStateList
                showChip.setTextColor(chipMoreColorText)
                showChip.text = chipMoreTitle + " (${childCount - i + 1})"
                showChip.isCheckable = false
                showChip.isSelected = false
                //при клике на chipMoreTitle выставляем maxRow на максимум и обновляем элементы
                //после добавляем chipHideTitle
                showChip.setOnClickListener {
                    maxRow = Int.MAX_VALUE
                    setChips(ArrayList(lastChipsList))

                    if (chipHideTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                        val hideChip = Chip(context)
                        hideChip.chipBackgroundColor = colorStateList
                        hideChip.setTextColor(chipMoreColorText)
                        hideChip.text = chipHideTitle
                        hideChip.isSelected = false
                        hideChip.isCheckable = false
                        //при клике на chipHideTitle выставляем maxRow на заданный и обновляем элементы
                        hideChip.setOnClickListener {
                            maxRow = maxRowDef
                            setChips(ArrayList(lastChipsList))
                        }
                        addView(hideChip)
                    }
                }
            }
```

В layout'е прописываем наш новый ChipGroup

```
<io.github.tiarait.extendedchipgroup.ExtendedChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/chip_group"
                app:maxRow="2"
                app:itemSpacing="6dp"
                app:additionalTextColor="#eee"
                app:additionalChipColor="@color/colorDarkBtn"
                app:additionalChipColorPressed="@color/colorDarkBtnSecondary"
                app:additionalChipMore="@string/btn_show"
                app:additionalChipHide="@string/btn_hide"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

где

```
maxRow (int) - максимальное количество строк ChipGroup
additionalTextColor (color) - цвет текста дополнительных кнопок
additionalChipColor (color) - цвет фона для доп кнопок (состояние покоя)
additionalChipColorPressed (color) - цвет фона для доп кнопок (при нажатии)
additionalChipMore (string) - заголовок для кнопки ЕЩЕ
additionalChipHide (string) - заголовок для кнопки скрытия
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто! Либу классную сделали Вы! Я начал делать как Вы предлагали выше, но знаний не хватило ). единственный момент, мне сейчас нужно сделать так, чтобы кнопка hide не уходило в самый последний ряд, а оставалась на том же месте где была кнопка more. Попробую разобраться в Вашем коде).

Comment: спасибо, пока только зачатки для либы. Насчет вопроса - можно попробовать кнопку самой первой сделать, тогда и скакать не будет и более менее смотреться. Еще ведь можно на любую кнопку завязать - при клике программно задаем колво рядов и вызываем upd(). На выходных еще мб еще что надумаю

Comment: Если будет время, не могли бы Вы помощь мне сделать логику такой, чтобы получить результат который я выше прикрепил. т.е. кнопка ЕЩЕ/СКРЫТЬ всегда должны быть последними на второй строке (просто по разному называются ).

Comment: У текста Chip элементов разные отступы спереди и сзади. На разных устройствах по разному. Пробовал  textEndPadding = 0 делать(не помогает), наблюдалось ли такое? Есть решение?

Comment: @SKULL не смотрел, но решение однозначно есть, скорее всего это из-за разных dpi. На выходных посмотрю, но лучше напишите в issues на гите  (а то могу забыть, + модели где это заметно)

Comment: даже если забыть про разные экраны и DPI, то в любом случае, у меня не получилось убрать отступы от теста. Создам наверное отдельный вопрос

Comment: в итоге проблема была в setTextSize. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200384/%d0%a3%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-end-padding-%d1%83-chip-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0