# Убрать end padding у Chip элемента

Tags: android, kotlin

Программно создается Chip (в коде пытался избавится от конечного отступа)

```
fun createChip(): Chip {
    val chip = Chip(context)
    chip.text = "dsg dfgs adfa sfasfsd s"

    chip.chipBackgroundColor = Color.GREEN
    chip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)

    chip.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14F)
    chip.chipStartPadding = 0F
    chip.chipEndPadding = 0F

    chip.closeIconStartPadding = 0F
    chip.closeIconEndPadding = 0F
    chip.closeIconSize = 0F

    chip.isCloseIconVisible = false
    chip.isCheckedIconVisible = false

    chip.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    chip.setPaddingRelative(0, 0, 0, 0)

    chip.textStartPadding = 0F
    chip.textEndPadding = 0F
    chip.includeFontPadding = false
    chip.minWidth = 0
    return chip
}
```

Chip - com.google.android.material.chip

вот результат (непонятно откуда там отступ в конце)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое Chip? Где и как он создается? Это точно отступ или может быть текст короче чем фон? Нужно больше информации

Comment: Фон это просто цвет, про Chip добавил инфу

Comment: имхо - с отступом chip воспринимается визуально более приятно, так что можете просто добавить его в начало и проблема решена))

Comment: отступы убрал, чтобы показать. А так я хочу чтобы с двух сторон было одинаково, а не по разному.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В моем случае проблема была в `chip.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14F)`

Решение подсмотрел тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/57397345/3671076